# Difference between sh and sh -c in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Consider I have script like given below.

demo.sh:

```
name=$1    
age=$2
echo $name
echo $age
```

when I execute the script like

```
sh demo.sh ARUN 24
```

Output is:

```
ARUN
24
```

But, When I execute the script like

```
sh -c demo.sh ARUN 24
```

Output is nothing.

I know if i use `sh -c` arguments will be assigned starting from `$0`. But only file name is getting assigned to `$0`.
How can i assign more than one parameters when is use `sh -c`?
Please explain me how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax instead:

```
sh -c "demo.sh ARUN 24"
```

In your case those two arguments where passed to the `sh` command, not the `demo.sh` script. Put them in quotes to pass them trought `sh` to the script.

Note the easiest way would be to make the script executable and add a hashbang (`#!`) line to it. The scripts would then look as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

name=$1
age=$2
echo $name
echo $age
```

Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x demo.sh
```

Then run it as follows (without the interpreter `sh`, the interpreter is now gathered from the `#!` line):

```
./demo.sh ARUN 24
```